# How to fetch the data in an S3 bucket using AWS Access Key and Secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created AWS Access Key and Secret Keys after following the requirements [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html)

and I have tried to get the data from a specific S3 bucket using them but I am getting `AccessDenied`

My code is below

```
    import { S3Client, ListObjectsCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

    export class AWS_S3Service {
        client: S3Client;
        constructor(accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string) {
            this.client = new S3Client({
                credentials: {
                    accessKeyId,
                    secretAccessKey,
                },
                region: 'us-east-1',
            });
        }

        async getAllDataInBucket(bucketName: string): Promise<any> {
            try {
                const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
                    Bucket: bucketName,
                });

                const response = await this.client.send(command);
                const objects = response.Contents;

                if (!objects || objects.length === 0) {
                    return [];
                }

                // Extract the keys (object names) from the objects list
                const keys = objects.map((object) => object.Key);

                return keys;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data from S3:', error);
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
    const accessKey = 'AK*****************5W';
    const secretKey = 'qNx******************************Br';
    (async () => {
        const newClient = new AWS_S3Service(accessKey, secretKey);
        const data = await newClient.getAllDataInBucket("my-testing-bucket")
        console.log(data);
        
    })();
```

what am I doing wrong here?

I need to know as well whether this is the correct way to get data from the S3 bucket, or there must be an existing Cognito user that needs to sign in then get a temporarily access key and secret key and use these keys to get data from the bucket?

I don't want to create any Identity Pool or Cognito users - so if that's the only way please inform me
[image: Security Credentials Tab]

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403 => a LOT of things could be at fault, there is no way for us to tell.

Comment: `AccessDenied` typically means that the credentials you are using do not have permission for the command you are using. Which line is generating the error? Is it `ListObjectsCommand`? If so, make sure that your IAM User has the `s3:ListBucket` permission.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my IAM user has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission, and I have created the Access and Secret Keys from the Security Credentials of this user, should these keys already have permission to access all buckets? Please check the screenshot above

Comment: Are you attempting to access a bucket owned by the same account as the IAM User? You can test permissions by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). First, add the credentials by using the `aws configure` command. Then, try `aws s3 ls` to try to list all the bucket names and `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` to list a particular bucket. That will confirm whether that user has sufficient permissions. Let us know what happens!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for your help! I have installed AWS CLI tool and tried `aws s3 ls`  to list all the bucket names and `aws s3 ls s3://my-testing-bucket` and still got `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`(same for `ListBuckets`), I wonder why I don't have access to do that even though I showed you that the user that I have created the Access and Secret Keys from does have the `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission, any idea on why that's happening?

Comment: Did you use `aws configure` to store the credentials? It might be that you also have credentials in Environment Variables that are overriding the credentials. You can check this by using `aws sts get-caller-identity` to display your identity -- confirm that it displays the ARN of the IAM User you are wanting to use.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah I did `aws configure` and I have set the credentials that I have recently generated, and when executed `aws sts get-caller-identity` to display my identity it returned my IAM user account that have the `AmazonS3FullAccess`

Comment: Well, either something is not what you think it is, or there is a [Service control policies (SCPs) - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) overriding those permissions. Nothing else should prevent an `aws s3 ls` command (with no bucket specified) from working.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein a permission boundary on the user entity could also prevent it, right!? @ OP: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html

Comment: @luk2302 I think a permission boundary would just deny the ability to grant permissions outside the boundary. That is, it prevents the "too many permissions" policy being created, rather than limiting the permissions already assigned to a user.